# $f(x,y) = \ln (1-x^2-y^2)$. What's the derivative?

Tags: partial-derivative

What's is the derivative of $f(x,y)= \ln(1-x^2-y^2)$?

I got it to $f_x(x,y)= 2x^-1$ and the same for $f_y(x,y)$, but that's obviously incorrect. How do I solve this problem properly?

Comment: You need to do chain rule to differentiate $\ln$ first.

Comment: fx(x,y)= 2x/(1-x^2-y^2) Is this correct?

Comment: Almost. It should be $-2x$ on top.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the chain rule,

$$f_x(x,y) = \frac{-2x}{1-x^2-y^2}$$

$$f_y(x,y) =  \frac{-2y}{1-x^2-y^2}$$